# Reorder UL dropdown, depending of direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap dropdown with list menu, which I need to reorder depending if dropdown goes up or down.

Here is my code, it checks if there is place to go up or down, but currently list order doesn't change.

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    //Distance of toolbar from viewport top minus header (100px)
    var scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset  = $(this).offset().top,
        distanceTop    = (elementOffset - scrollTop - 100);
    //Distance to bottom of viewport
    var distanceBottom = $(window).height() - distanceTop - 150;
    //Get height of dropdown
    var dropdownMoreHeight = $("#dropdown ul").innerHeight();

    //Check which direction is more room for dropdown
    if (distanceTop < dropdownMoreHeight && distanceTop < distanceBottom){
        $(this).addClass("go-down");
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("go-down");
    }
});
```

The code for reversed ul list I've found so far is 
`$('#dropdown').append($('#dropdown').find('li').get().reverse());`

**The question is** how do I reverse it only once when dropdown goes down?

Comment: Elvis, I've had a look at your code. It might help if you put together your script and html in a jsfiddle.

Comment: hi, made similar fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y681zvam/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got solution my self, if anyone interested here is Jsfiddle

```
var originalList = $('#dropdown').find('li').get();
    $('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
      //Check which direction is more room for dropdown
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50){
          $("#dropdown").addClass("go-down").append(originalList.reverse());
        }
    });
    $('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        if ($("#dropdown").hasClass( "go-down" )){
        $("#dropdown").removeClass("go-down").append(originalList.reverse());
      }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/elviscau/y681zvam/14/

Answer (score 0):

## revised answer

I've modified the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/n1p4k4tn/) to declare the dropdown/up lists first, before the click event. Then we simply call the **downlist** or **uplist** depending on the logic.

```
// set the dropdown/up lists as variable before the click event

var downlist = $('#dropdown').find('li').get();
var uplist = downlist.reverse();

$("#button").on('click', function(){

    //Check which direction is more room for dropdown
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50)         {

        // Now, replace the list with the var downlist
        $("#dropdown").addClass("go-down").find('ul').append(downlist);
    }else{

        // Now, replace the list with the var downlist
        $("#dropdown").removeClass("go-down").find('ul').append(uplist);
    }
});
```

### old answer

After you provided the jsfiddle, it looked fairly straight forward. I simply added the reverse script after your ELSE.

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){

    //Check which direction is more room for dropdown
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50)         {
        $("#dropdown").addClass("go-down");
    }else{
        $("#dropdown").removeClass("go-down");
        /*here*/
        $('#dropdown').append($('#dropdown').find('li').get().reverse());
    }
});
```

See my forked [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/n1p4k4tn/). 
Now, if it opens up, it displays:

- 8
- 7
- 6
- 5
- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1

and, if it opens down, it displays

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8

I believe that is what you were asking for.

Comment: Not exactly. Now if you scroll up, it opens reversed.

Comment: Confused with what you are expecting as a result.Maybe express to us what you are expecting to see in the following instances ( dropdown = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ) and ( dropup = 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 ).

Comment: Yes. ( dropdown = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ) and ( dropup = 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 ). It should always be in this order. Your fiddle works only on first two clicks, click1 = ok, scroll down, click 2 = ok, scroll up again, the order of dropup is the same as dropdown. Should be always ( dropdown = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ) and ( dropup = 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 )

Comment: @Elvis Thanks for clarifying. I have updated the jsfiddle and i've revised my answer above. I believe this works the way you wanted it to now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think the order in your fiddle always showing (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ). Maybe I'm missing something. :(